# Parsing an ambigious language

Tags: xtext

I'm trying to define a grammar for a 4GL language which is pretty ambigious and I'm having problems projecting this with a Xtext grammar.

The following grammar is what I've come up with until now:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl hidden(WS)

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Program:
    name=PROGRAMID
    variables+=Variable*
;

Variable:
    level=INT name=VARIABLEID definition=TypeDefinition;

TypeDefinition hidden():
    '(' type=Datatype length=INT ')'
;

Datatype:
    Alpha
    | Num;

Alpha:
    'A';

Num:
    'N';

terminal PROGRAMID:
    ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')+
;

terminal VARIABLEID:
    ('+')? ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '-' | '_' | '/' | '#' | '$' | '&' | '@')
    ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '_' | '/' | '#' | '$' | '&' | '@')*;

terminal INT returns ecore::EInt:
    ('0'..'9')+;

terminal STRING:
    '"' ('\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\' | '"'))* '"' |
    "'" ('\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\' | "'"))* "'";

terminal WS:
    (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+;

terminal ANY_OTHER:
    .;
```

It should be able to parse something like this:

```
PROG01
1 MYVARIABLE (A14)
```

But it is failing on two things.

1) mismatched input 'MYVARIABLE' expecting RULE_VARIABLEID

If I add a - or something else to distinguish it from PROGRAMID it works.

2)
mismatched input '' expecting RULE_INT
no viable alternative at input 'A14'

I can't force it to **not** have a whitespace inbetween.

Is it possible to let Xtext parse such a grammar or do I have to use something like ANTLR to create the AST myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you have a look at the possibilities xtext offers to use an external lexer eg. https://github.com/TypeFox/xtext-jflex

Comment: Hi Christian, no I didn't know about that possibility yet. Is there anything like a blogpost or something to guide me?

Comment: No I don't know of any